# Kestrel no Mono Error -14 EFAULT bad address in system call argument

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, mono, kestrel-http-server

First of all, I realise that AspNetCore is no longer supported or tested on Mono.

Still, I have an existing project (AspNet 1.0.0-rc1-final), which targets net461 and I need to migrate it to AspNetCore 1.1.0. After a couple hours of struggle, I did it, only to be surprised by it no longer working on Mono.

I tried switching to netcoreapp1.1 but ended np in DLL hell - way to many unsupported libraries to go for it.

I'm using Docker with Mono and additional LibUV installed

```
FROM debian:wheezy

MAINTAINER Jo Shields <jo.shields@xamarin.com>

#based on dockerfile by Michael Friis <friism@gmail.com>

ENV MONO_VERSION 4.6.2.7

RUN apt-get update \
  && apt-get install -y curl \
  && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

RUN apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv-keys 3FA7E0328081BFF6A14DA29AA6A19B38D3D831EF

RUN echo "deb http://download.mono-project.com/repo/debian wheezy/snapshots/$MONO_VERSION main" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mono-xamarin.list \
  && apt-get update \
  && apt-get install -y binutils mono-devel ca-certificates-mono fsharp mono-vbnc nuget referenceassemblies-pcl \
  && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* /tmp/*


# Install libuv for Kestrel from source code (binary is not in wheezy and one in jessie is still too old)
# Combining this with the uninstall and purge will save us the space of the build tools in the image
RUN LIBUV_VERSION=1.9.1 \
    && apt-get -qq update \
    && apt-get -qqy install autoconf automake build-essential libtool \
    && curl -sSL https://github.com/libuv/libuv/archive/v${LIBUV_VERSION}.tar.gz | tar zxfv - -C /usr/local/src \
    && cd /usr/local/src/libuv-$LIBUV_VERSION \
    && sh autogen.sh && ./configure && make && make install \
    && rm -rf /usr/local/src/libuv-$LIBUV_VERSION \
    && ldconfig \
    && apt-get -y purge autoconf automake build-essential libtool \
    && apt-get -y autoremove \
    && apt-get -y clean \
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*
```

Every http request to my app causes a Kestrel error:

```
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel[14]
      Connection id "0HL2PMPE1RGS7" communication error.
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Internal.Networking.UvException: Error -14 EFAULT bad address in system call argument
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel[20]
      Connection id "0HL2PMPE1RGS7" request processing ended abnormally.
System.IO.IOException: Error -14 EFAULT bad address in system call argument ---> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Internal.Networking.UvException: Error -14
EFAULT bad address in system call argument
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
  at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Internal.Http.SocketInput.CheckConnectionError () [0x00020] in <43555eec0dc34d2abb4f01227fa5a2e9>:0
  at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Internal.Http.SocketInput.GetResult () [0x00013] in <43555eec0dc34d2abb4f01227fa5a2e9>:0
  at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Internal.Http.Frame`1+<RequestProcessingAsync>d__2[TContext].MoveNext () [0x00194] in <43555eec0dc34d2abb4f01227fa5a2e9
>:0
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel[14]
      Connection id "0HL2PMPE1RGS8" communication error.
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Internal.Networking.UvException: Error -14 EFAULT bad address in system call argument
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel[20]
      Connection id "0HL2PMPE1RGS8" request processing ended abnormally.
System.IO.IOException: Error -14 EFAULT bad address in system call argument ---> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Internal.Networking.UvException: Error -14
EFAULT bad address in system call argument
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
  at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Internal.Http.SocketInput.CheckConnectionError () [0x00020] in <43555eec0dc34d2abb4f01227fa5a2e9>:0
  at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Internal.Http.SocketInput.GetResult () [0x00013] in <43555eec0dc34d2abb4f01227fa5a2e9>:0
  at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Internal.Http.Frame`1+<RequestProcessingAsync>d__2[TContext].MoveNext () [0x00194] in <43555eec0dc34d2abb4f01227fa5a2e9
>:0
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel[14]
      Connection id "0HL2PMPE1RGS9" communication error.
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Internal.Networking.UvException: Error -14 EFAULT bad address in system call argument
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel[20]
      Connection id "0HL2PMPE1RGS9" request processing ended abnormally.
System.IO.IOException: Error -14 EFAULT bad address in system call argument ---> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Internal.Networking.UvException: Error -14
EFAULT bad address in system call argument
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
  at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Internal.Http.SocketInput.CheckConnectionError () [0x00020] in <43555eec0dc34d2abb4f01227fa5a2e9>:0
  at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Internal.Http.SocketInput.GetResult () [0x00013] in <43555eec0dc34d2abb4f01227fa5a2e9>:0
  at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Internal.Http.Frame`1+<RequestProcessingAsync>d__2[TContext].MoveNext () [0x00194] in <43555eec0dc34d2abb4f01227fa5a2e9
>:0
```

Did anyone manage to make AspNetCore v 1.1 run on Mono? Any help appreciated.

Comment: https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/issues/5088

Comment: @stuartd Did you mean the comment 'techcap commented on 5 Aug 2016' (creating symbolic link)? If so, it changed nothing. :(

Comment: I have the same problem. Did you manage to solve it?

Answer (score 0):

My temporary solution:

1. Downgrade Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel to 1.0.3
2. Remove System.Runtime.InteropServices.RuntimeInformation.dll from outputs (because of dotnet/corefx#9012)
3. Downgrade Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Console to 1.0.2 (because 1.1.1 refuses to use System.Runtime.InteropServices.RuntimeInformation.dll from mono, but 1.0.2 - don't)
4. It works!